# From a branch to the associated work items in TFS

Tags: git, tfs

In the TFS web interface I can attach a git branch to a work item. I can then click on a link to go from the work item to the branch.

But I don't see how I can go in the other direction. Is there away to go from a branch to the associated work items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there away to go from a branch to the associated work items?

No, there isn't a way to achieve that. The branch is mainly focus on files/codes in source control but not the work items...

Comment: Ok. Thank you for confirming this.